# Prove $f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)-\frac{2}{\pi}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(4nx)}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$ Fourier Series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

$f(x)= \begin{cases} \sin(2x),0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{2}\\0,\frac{\pi}{2}\le x\le\pi\end{cases}$

Prove that f(x)= $\frac{1}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(4nx)}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$

I figured $a_n$ , $b_n$ , and $a_0$ would be found using:

$a_n$= $\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)\cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})dx$ = $\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(2x)\cos(2nx)dx$ = $\frac{2}{\pi}(\frac{\cos(\pi n)+1}{2-2n^2})$

$b_n$ = $\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)\sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})dx$ =  $\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(2x)\sin(2nx)dx$ = $\frac{2}{\pi}(\frac{2\sin(\pi n)}{2-2n^2})$ = 0 since "n" is an integer.

$a_0$ = $\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)dx$ = $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(2x)dx$ = $\frac{1}{\pi}$

Then, putting that all together into a Fourier Series we get:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[(\frac{2}{\pi})(\frac{\cos(\pi n)+1}{2-2n^2})\cos(2nx)]$$

which reduces to $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(4nx)}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$$ (which I found thanks to Winther's comment below!)

But I am still unsure of where the $\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$ term comes from. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Note that $\cos(\pi n) = (-1)^n$ and $(-1)^n - 1 = 0$ when $n$ is even and $-2$ when $n$ is odd. Try to split the sum into even $n$ ($n = 2k$ for $k=1,2,\ldots$) and odd $n$ ($n = 2k+1$ for $k=0,1,2,\ldots$).

Comment: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow 1} \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{\sin(\pi n)}{1-n^2} = \frac{1}{2} \,. $$